# Android - Custom CheckedTextView in listView doesn't get checked on click/disables SINGLE_CHOICE mode

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, checkedtextview

- When I use the layout from : `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` as list item, the checkbox gets checked on click and everything is fine.
- However when I use the layout :

```
<CheckedTextView android:id="@+id/choice_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckedTextView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"/>
```

The checkbox won't get toggled.

- If I implement an `onClickListener` like this in the list `adapter` :

```
((CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dp_quiz_answer_choice_item)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
    }
});
```

`SINGLE_CHOICE` mode gets disabled(any number of check boxes can be enabled).

- If I implement the `setOnItemClickListener` in the list view the checkbox won't get toggled.

```
mChoiceList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int item,
                    long id) {
        mChoiceList.setItemChecked(item, true);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to have a custom layout for `SINGLE_CHOICE` mode `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kind of weird for me, after many other experiments I learnt that having the `id` of the `CheckedTextView` same as the one used in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` worked for me. The id is `@android:id/text1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` where it should be `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle` for SINGLE_CHOICE